# make my application start when boot complete on/off

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-manifest

Heloo everyone

im new to android development
and im developing an android application for my graduation project
my application must start when the device boot up
so to that i put these lines in the **AndroidManifest** file

```
<!--this to make app run at start up-->
    <receiver android:name="MyIntentReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

so my program run autmaticlly when boot complete.
my question is how to stop this by user?? i want to put a toggle button on/off
for this option so the user can chose if he want the app to start automaticlly in background or manually ???

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds pretty straight forward.  Basically, when the phone starts, the Receiver class "MyIntentReceiver" will run. Inside this receiver you can put code based on user preferences to either start the application or do nothing.  The toggle would be a CheckBoxPreference in the user preferences.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you actually after i put this question , this idea came to my mind and i did it now and sure its a good idea and will work,, thank you

Comment: i have another question , when the program run at start up , i want it to run in background, so i used the method moveTaskToBack(true); and it work but the question is, is this the good way?? or there is a better way?  thx

Comment: It sounds like you want to start a service from your receiver. A service will run in the background. I would look into that.

Answer (score 1):

> so my program run automatically when boot complete.

I would say no to that. It is rather you receiver gets notified when boot is completed. From that point on, your program has to decide to fire up your activity/service in `onReceive()` method of your receiver.

Thus, you will need to save a preference to give option to user. When your receiver gets notified, check the pref setting set by user. For more information about saving preference, you can refer to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref